# Is a custom ASP.NET Model Binder supposed to convert values passed to Url.Action into their correct string representations?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have custom model binders for date-times and numbers. They work well converting my request  string values into valid strongly typed values.

Now I need `Url.Action` to use the Model Binder to do the opposite. I pass in a data-time or a number and I need it to know how to convert it to string.

Is the ASP.NET Model Binding supposed to work in the other way as well? Converting values passed to Url.Action into their correct string representation?

If not, is there a way to achieve that?

**EDIT**

I asking because I tested and it doesn't work but I don't know if I'm missing something

Answer (score 1):

> Is the ASP.NET Model Binding supposed to work in the other way as
>   well? Converting values passed to Url.Action into their correct string
>   representation?

No. Model Binding not works in other way. That's the job of routing infrastructure.

> If not, is there a way to achieve that?

One idea I can see is by creating a custom `RouteValueDictionary` class.

```
public class CustomRouteValueDictionary: RouteValueDictionary
{
    public CustomRouteValueDictionary(object values)
    {
        foreach (var prop in values.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            var value = prop.GetValue(values, null);

            if (value.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                value = ((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
            }

            Add(prop.Name, value);
        }
    }
}
```

There are built-in Action methods for `UrlHelper` that takes `RouteValueDictionary` as parameter and you can pass this `CustomRouteValueDictionary` to it.

Ex.

**Instead of this**

```
@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController", new { dt = DateTime.Now })

Output: /SomeController/SomeAction?dt=07%2F21%2F2012%2019%3A21%3A59
```

**You can use**

```
@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController", new 
   CustomRouteValueDictionary(new { dt = DateTime.Now }))

Output: /SomeController/SomeAction?dt=2012-07-21
```

You can even create custom extension methods that will accept the anonymous object directly and create `CustomRouteValueDictionary` inside it.